# Is there any way to exchange the name of a table with a current table online?

Tags: oracle

A table currently syncing using ogg on target side has a few differences with the source side. So I will resync the table to a new name on target side alone. But how can I exchange the table name with the older one online? Just like the dbms_redefinition.finish_redef_table does? (including locking the two tables, rename a to c, rename b to a, rename c to b,...).

I've tried some common ways like "lock table test_imp.test_rename in exclusive mode nowait", "select ... for update", but it does not work.

Comment: What commands exactly have you tried and what about them "not works"?